# How to make job scheduler?

Tags: java, multithreading, scheduled-tasks, threadpool

I want to schedule a thread that execute a task at 3'o clock in the morning every day. I have made scheduler using TimerTask given by Java, quatrz API, and so on. But TimeTask and all were unable to meet my requirement. Because my requirement is my scheduler should not run any process to check the server time. Means Scheduler application must not be on run mode, just to check the server time to run execute a task.

I was running infinite loop to check the server time. When it is 3'o clock, my if condition is used to be satisfied and thread is allowed to execute a task.

But the problem with this approach is this infinite loop is in the running mode that insist application to run until 3'o clock of next morning. Is there another way that start this application every day 3'clock without this redundant running mode.

Comment: Can you please add the code you are referring to?

Comment: for(;;)
{
if(currentTime==3'o clock)
{
//excute task that will take 50 minutes 
}
}

Comment: Please add the code to your question, that makes it more visible to people trying to help. Also, I assume that "3'o clock" is pseudocode, because that wouldn't work as actual code. So please add the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look to isocline's [Clockwork](https://github.com/isocline/clockwork) it's a java process engine. It is capable of coding various functions more efficiently than Quartz, and has specific execution function.

```
package isocline.clockwork.examples.basic;

import isocline.clockwork.*;
import isocline.clockwork.descriptor.CronDescriptor;
import org.junit.Test;

public class ClockRepeat implements Work {

    public long execute(WorkEvent event) throws InterruptedException {
        //TODO

        return WAIT;
    }

    @Test
    public void case1() throws Exception {

        WorkProcessor processor = WorkProcessorFactory.getDefaultProcessor();
        processor.createSchedule(new CronDescriptor("* 3 * * *"), this).activate();

        processor.awaitShutdown();
    }
}
```